# If Noise is an interface and Animal is a class that implements it, what is the meaning of Noise n = new Animal()?

Tags: java, interface

For example Noise is an interface and Animal is a class that implements Noise.
Why can I write under main:

```
Noise n = new Animal();
```

And what is the meaning of it?

Answer (score 0):

Because [interfaces can be used as types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html). You are then restricted to the methods declared in the interface, independent of the implementing class.

It means "I want a new animal to be stored in `n`, but I will ever only need it's `Noise` features, so let me only use those methods on `n`".

Comment: But I can access the toString() as well

Comment: `toString()` belongs to `Object`, so it is available on all descendants.